# Component Manger/Web Setup Wizard redirects to "updating application" immediately

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.2, component-manager, web-setup-wizard

I need to install a module via the `Component Manager` for an M2 2.1.2 instance that seems to be broken here and there to put it midly. There does not seem to be a Composer option, unfortunately, for this module (Shipworks). I'll check with SW, but I'm trying to figure out why the Component Manager is broken.

This instance's `Component Manager` or `Web Setup Wizard` as named in the admin menu (`mysite.com/setup`) immediately redirects to the `New Purchases` page (`mysite.com/update/index.php`), where it says "Update application is running" and gets stuck there.

There is no log of any kind, and the page constantly makes a call out to `mysite.conm/update/index.php/status` every few seconds. to no end Response back is always the same saying `isUpdateInProgress` is `true`.

What could be wrong that I can't go to the Component Manager page?